# How to create or specify associations in RSpec (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model, associations, factories

There are two models:
**student** and **subjects**

With these associations:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subjects
end

class Subjects < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
end
```

In **controllers**, I can enter the following to get the subjects being taken by a **student** with id=1:

```
subjects = Student.find(1).subjects
```

**Question**: How do I do the same thing with factories in RSpec?

In my test, I have the following:

```
let(:student) { create(:student) }
let(:subjects) { create_list(:subject, rand(10), student: student) }
```

But, doing the following gives empty collection:

```
student.subjects
```

Comment: maybe `rand(10)` return zero

Answer (score 0):

So I’m going to answer my own question.

It’s as easy as:

`student.subjects << subjects`

`student.subjects .class` will now be `Subject::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`

[reference](https://gist.github.com/xuncheng/5908269)

Comment: You could also use `let!` on subjects, like:  
`let!(:subjects) { create_list(:subject, rand(10), student: student) }`.  


`let` is lazy-evaluated, while `let!` is always invoked.   


More here:  
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let