# Working with rails associations in rspec - associations methods behave unpredictably

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

### Issue:

When i define a variable in a spec and then call an association methods they don't seem to consistently query the database. Some seem stuck. I would be really greatful for any help on this, as I had this issue before and only solved it by querying the database explicitly with `find`. This seems to persist across `let`, `let!` and `before` blocks to different extents. It does however work with method definitions or through calling `find`. My question is how I can use the `let!` syntax here or anything provided by rspec rather then my no so pretty hack.

---

### Progress:

@engineersmnky pointed to the issue of the `ActiveRecord` objects and relations not being loaded. I'm working on figuring out the issue there and will write once I find the solution

---

For example this doesn't work as expected with `let` but works with `let!` (The counts vary unexpetedly):

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Form::Adaption, type: :model do
  context 'when a revision gets created' do
    let(:app) { create(:form_application, revision_counter: 1) } # NOTE: this creates an adaption
    let(:rev_adap) { create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'revision', application: app) }

    it '...' do
      doc_adap = create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'document', application: app)
      expect(doc_adap.application.revision?).to be true
      # NOTE: DB Cleaner gem destroys doc_adaption
    end

    describe '...' do
      it '...' do
        # ISSUE:
        puts "app.adaptions.count: #{app.adaptions.count}" # => 1
        puts "rev_adap.application.adaptions.count: #{rev_adap.application.adaptions.count}" # => 2
        puts "App.find(adap.id).adaptions #{Form::Application.find(rev_adap.application_id).adaptions.count}" # => 2 

        create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'document', application: app)

        # Utter Confusion: 
        puts "app.adaptions.count: #{app.adaptions.count}" # => 3
        puts "rev_adap.application.adaptions.count: #{rev_adap.application.adaptions.count}" # => 3
        puts "App.find(adap.id).adaptions #{Form::Application.find(rev_adap.application_id).adaptions.count}" # => 3 

        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When switching to the *not* lazy evaluated `let!` it does work with the debug `puts` calls.

```rb
    let!(:app) { create(:form_application, revision_counter: 1) }
    let!(:rev_adap) { create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'revision', application: app) }
```

`=> 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3` in the `puts` up above.

However the actual test I want to run still fails because `app.adaptions` returns an empty array, even though in the `puts` one line above it printing a count of 4.

```rb
# i use let! to define the app and rev_adap but this also happens with regular let 

      it 'the relevant it block from above' do
        # ... 
        post_revision_doc_adap = create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'document', application: app)
        puts "Adap count: #{app.adaptions.count}" # => 4 as expected
        pp app.adaptions.first # => nil
        app.adaptions.sample(1).revision_manager
        # ISSUE: => undefined method `revision_manager' for []:Array
```

So `app` seems 'stuck', but that changes on the context. It doesn't query the database for changes in its associated adaptions when defined with `let` due to the lazy-loading i think, however the problem even persists with `let!` in other places. This is kind of my main question. How can this even happen, the same thing: `app.adaptions` returns something in one line and in the next returns something else, and calling `count` doesn't change anything about `app.adaptions` (*edited the last sentence in to clarify my question*)

### Useful Debugger Info

When stepping through the test with a debugger just now, I found these weird evaluations at the first print line:

- app.adaptions.count = 2
- app = Form::Application:some_address
- app.adaptions = **EMPTY** Form::Adaption::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

  - this holds the table information for `Form::Adaption` but doesn't hold any actual values in `@values` or anywhere. Here and there are some bytes and maybe it's because of it being a proxy but i think this situation is quite suspicous to be the cause

### 'Fixing' it through method calls

I get the same final error when i `app` and `rev_adap` as instance variables in a `before` block.
However when i define `app` and `rev_adap` as methods like so:

```rb
def app
  @__a ||= create(:form_application, revision_counter: 1)
  Form::Application.find(@__a.id)
end

def rev_adap
  @__a2 ||= create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'revision', application: app)
  Form::Adaption.find(@__a2.id)
end
```

and run the `it` block in question it does kinda work:

```rb
# ...
doc_adap = create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'document', application: app)
# ...

pp app.adaptions # => collection witth four adaptions as expected
pp app.adaptions.sample() # => collection with one adaption ( number of adaptions after factory bot done )
```

However i still get the same weird count behavior as at the top with `let`.

I understand that this is not a rails related issue as in the rails console it is no problem to define `app` and create new `Form::Adaptions` for it and then have them reflected in `app.adaptions.count`. I also didn't find anything in the creation process that's in the regular app and not in FactoryBot where the application is looked up. Only `save!` gets called on it. I didn't look into the rails internals here.

I tried poking around in the ActiveRecord Association Source because i didn't really find anything explictly regarding "rspec test rails associations".

I couldn't relate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68218967/how-to-create-or-specify-associations-in-rspec-rails) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739761/cant-access-non-persisted-associations-in-rspec) to my issue. The first seems similar but is not very detailed, the second one didn't seem to be related, because i definitely persist all the FactoryBot Usages through the `create` strategy.

### Factories

form/applications_factory.rb :

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "#{Rails.root}/lib/constants/test_constants"

FactoryBot.define do

  factory :form_adaption, class: 'Form::Adaption' do
    association :application, factory: :form_application
    association :user, factory: %i[user random]
    action_type { NO_ARGS_ACTION_TYPES.sample }
    # set deadline temporarily to get around deadline presence validation
    # and update it in after create hook
    deadline { 1.year.from_now }

    after :create, class: 'Form::Adaption' do |adap, _evaluator|
      adap.update(deadline: TestConstants::Adaption::DEADLINES[adap.action_type])
    end
  end
end
```

form/applications_factory.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :form_application, class: 'Form::Application' do
    association :student, factory: :student
    association :semester, factory: :semester

    after :create, class: 'Form::Application' do |app|
      user = create(:user, :random)
      AdaptionManager.new(user, app).create_application
      # this saves an Adaption
    end
  end
end
```

### Testing Setup:

I use factory_bot and the db_cleaner gem in addition to rspec and rspec_rails.

Ruby version is 2.7.2, rails is on 6.0.6.1

Rspec Versions are:
RSpec 3.12

- rspec-core 3.12.1
- rspec-expectations 3.12.2
- rspec-mocks 3.12.3
- rspec-rails 5.1.2
- rspec-support 3.12.0

Comment: @engineersmnky hey yes i don't see where the problem could lie as the factories seem really straightforward, i added them now though. The only things there are the extension i'm calling but thats really just a key value thing to clean up the factory and tests. And the call to `AdaptionManager` in the application factory seems like a non-issue to me as that just creates an adaption for the application and doesn't make any queries except in the `save!` call there when the adaption gets saved. I think its this thing in the debugger section tbh.

Comment: Still a little confused as to what your inquiry is here but `app` creates an `Adaption` (in `after :create` via `AdaptionManager` based on your comment),  so `app.adaptions.count` reports 1, then `rev_adap` creates an `Adaption` (becuase that's what the factory does) so `rev_adap.application.adaptions.count` reports 2, then you create a new one `create(:form_adaption, action_type: 'document', application: app)` so each mechanism reports 3 via `count` (which is a SQL query). What were you expecting?

Comment: ah ok its good to know that `count` is an SQL query. Hearing it back from you the `count` results actually make sense with the difference between `let` and `let!`, thank you!    
My issue is this thing that when using the `let!` definition i still end up with the issue that while `app.adaptions.count` returns the right number `app.adaptions` returns `nil`. is that because `app.adaptions` doesn't trigger an SQL query? because it in the rails console it did. This dilemna is maybe more clear in the edit i wrote on the debugger results.

Comment: If `app.adaptions` has already been loaded then then `count` could return any number but `app.adaptions` could be empty. You could use `app.adaptions.reload` and see what happens (you will need to figure out why you need to do this and try and avoid that)

Comment: thanks :) yeah doing reload does work. Do you maybe pointers in what direction i should looking to fix this? I'm not so experienced and don't have a solid understanding of how this can come to be.

Comment: I cannot really assist without understanding the entire test but if you call `app.adaptions` and interact with that response at all then the loaded flag will be set to `true` and subsequent calls will not reload this data e.g. `expect(app.adaptions.first.id).to eq(7)` then later you call `rev_adap` the newly created `Adaption` will not be loaded into `app.adaptions` without a `reload`. Generally speaking this would mean your tests are doing too much and should be rewritten to isolate testing but again this is impossible to determine without seeing the failing test.

Comment: ok thank you a lot! i will read up on it and hopefully write up the solution once i figured it out. the test only failed as in the error being raised in 
`app.adaptions.sample(1).revision_manager # ISSUE: => undefined method revision_manager' for []:Array`   
but i think with your help so far i can figure it somehow :)